# Using Ant Javac Adaptor

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am trying to use the Eclipse compiler to perform my ant builds. Using this document http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm I am trying to make my set-up. But i face the following error

```
Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter
```

What is the issue?

My aim is to run an Ant build outside of Eclipse but using the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: Show us how you are trying to use this in Ant.

Comment: `<property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>`

Answer (score 0):

To use the

```
<property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
```

method inside Eclipse your Ant script must be shown in the 'Run > External Tools Configurations' menu in the 'Ant' section. In the configuration for your Ant script your **must** specify 'Run in the same JRE as the workspace' on the JRE tab.

To use this outside of Eclipse you need the `org.eclipse.jdt.coreXXX.jar` and the `jdtCompilerAdapter.jar` (extracted from the jdt jar). You need to put **both** these jars on the Ant classpath either by putting them in the Ant library folder or using the `-lib` option.

Comment: Thanks for the note. But how do i run it outside of Eclipse? I thought I just had to put the `jdtCompilerAdapter.jar` file into the `ANT_HOME/lib` location.

Comment: You need both the jdtCompilerAdapter and org.eclipse.jdt.core jars. Added to answer.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have added them to the lib of my Ant directory. I would like to know if its possible to compile using the eclipse compiler and JRE 8?

Answer (score 0):

add ecj as dependency ...

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
      <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```